# Initialization of new instance in Python

Tags: python

I am writing unit tests fro tic-tat-toe on Python. And I have been extremely confused when noticed that my play object doesn't reinstantiate itself every method.

Here what I'm talking about:

```
def test_satisfactory_field_occupation(self):
        play = tictactoe.Play()
        play.make_move("+", 1, 1)
        self.assertEqual(play.check_satisfaction(1, 1), "Field has been already occupied, try again")

def test_satisfactory_success(self):
        play = tictactoe.Play()
        self.assertEqual(play.check_satisfaction(1, 1), "Ok")
```

And I caught exception:

```
FAIL: test_satisfactory_success (__main__.TestPlay)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergei_rudenkov/PycharmProjects/hello_world/tic-tac-toe/tictactoe_test.py", line 23, in test_satisfactory_success
    self.assertEqual(play.check_satisfaction(1, 1), "Ok")
AssertionError: 'Field has been already occupied, try again' != 'Ok'
```

The Play class is:

```
class Play(object):
    game = [['-', '-', '-'],
            ['-', '-', '-'],
            ['-', '-', '-']]

    move_count = 1
    finished = False

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(map(str, self.game))

    def check_finished(self):
        result = False
        for i in range(2):
            if self.game[i][0] == self.game[i][1] == self.game[i][2] != '-':
                result = self.game[i][0]
            elif self.game[0][i] == self.game[1][i] == self.game[2][i] != '-':
                result = self.game[i][0]
        if self.game[0][0] == self.game[1][1] == self.game[2][2] != '-':
            return self.game[0][0]
        elif self.game[0][2] == self.game[1][1] == self.game[2][0] != '-':
            return self.game[0][2]
        elif not any("-" in row for row in self.game):
            return "Draw"
        else:
            return result

    def make_move(self, sign, x, y):
        self.game[x][y] = sign
        self.move_count += 1
        self.finished = self.check_finished()
        print self

    def check_satisfaction(self, x, y):
        try:
            x, y = int(x), int(y)
        except ValueError:
            return "Please enter integers, try again"
        if not (0 <= x <= 2 and 0 <= y <= 2):
            return "Arguments greater then 2 or less then 0 are not allowed, try again"
        if self.game[x][y] != '-':
            return "Field has been already occupied, try again"
        return "Ok"

    def winner(self):
        if self.finished == '+':
            return "First player (+) has won!"
        elif self.finished == '0':
            return "Second player (0) has won!"
        elif self.finished == 'Draw':
            return "The result is draw!"
```

Please, understand me correctly: I came from java and was considered each method has it's own stack but what I am seeing highly amazes me. Could someone help me to understand what is happening?

Comment: Could you explain the behavior you were expecting?  It isn't clear from the question.

Comment: You are right, but I call `play = tictactoe.Play()` doesn't it equal to `java` `new SomeObject()' keyword statement?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your tests. Arey you sure, `play.check_satisfaction(1, 1)` is not *always* returning `Field has been ...`, even for a *new* `Play`? Show us `Play.__init__` and `Play.check_satisfaction`.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ could you share the relevant parts of your code for `Play`?

Comment: One "dumb" question to ask: are you sure that `tictactoe.Play()` really does return a fresh instance? or is something hanging around statically, at the class level? Try putting these two methods in different subclasses of `unittest.TestCase` and see if you still raise — I bet you won't.

Comment: @Tichodroma, `Play.check_satisfaction` is ok. When I shuffle order of my tests it works ok. So play instance looks like singleton. But I don't want it to be singleton. I don't have `__init__` method, should I?

Comment: Most likely you're operating on class methods, not instance methods (especially if you're background is java, where no explicit `self`/`this` is required.

Comment: @BrianO, I completely unsure. It's matter of my question

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ Please show us the code of `Play`. All of it. [Edit] your question, please.

Comment: @Rogalski I think you're on the right track.

Comment: A singleton, eh? Perhaps it isn't a clean slate. Again, try putting these two methods into two different `TestCase`s.

Comment: `Play` code is added

Comment: alright, `game`, `move_count` and `finished` are what you would call static in Java.

Comment: There you go: `game` is a class-level variable, and it doesn't get cleared. You would & should do that in an `__init__` method. Better still, make it an instance attribute, not a class attribute.

Comment: Thanks, People! It makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Play(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.game = [['-', '-', '-'],
                    ['-', '-', '-'],
                    ['-', '-', '-']]

        self.move_count = 1
        self.finished = False
```

Make sure you access these member variables using the `self.` prefix *always* in all other methods of the class:

- `self.game`
- `self.move_count`
- `self.finished`

Take a look at the [Python tutorial: 9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring you list "game" as "static".
Means that each instance will share the same list. Move the "game" declaration inside the constructor, and then you should be fine.

```
class Play(object):
   def __init__(self):    

        self.game = [['-', '-', '-'],
            ['-', '-', '-'],
            ['-', '-', '-']]
```

The reason for that is that when you declare the list at class level, that list gets allocated at parsing time, when they generate the "class object", you could access the game list with Play.game. This should already give you an idea of the scope of the game list. Here a simplified example of what is happening with a list declared at class level:

```
class Play:
    game =[0]


p1 = Play()
print p1.game
p1.game[0] =1
p2 = Play()
print p2.game
```

Comment: Right: first there has to **be** a constructor :) (`__init__`).

Comment: Probably should do the same for `more_count` and `finished`.

Comment: Without a doubt, yes. All of 'em.

Comment: Also, please don't call lists arrays.

Comment: @timgeb, you are right, I changed it in the comment

Comment: You're still calling it array three times. And it's not "each class".

Comment: it did not take the edits i did in the first run, think it conflicted with community edits. anyway fixed again , and "each class" aswell.

Comment: @BrianO what constructor are you referring to?

Comment: @MarcoGiordano The `__init__` method.

Comment: @BrianO Yes I know what a constructor is. but why you say in my code there has to be a constructor? In the first example there is one, in the second example there was no need for one to explain the point. Also having a constructor is not an hard requirement.

Comment: I know you know what a constructor is: you used the term, and I was saying that OP doesn't have one in his `Play` class. I don't understand your point or question. I'm well aware that `__init__` methods aren't mandatory. Your second example never wipes the gameboad clean, which is basically OP's problem. Calling `tictactoe.Play()` should return a fresh, blank instance of the game. `object.__init__` certainly isn't going to do that for you.

Comment: @BrianO my bad than, I did not understand that you were referring to OP question. My apologies. 
M.

Comment: Ah I see. No problem.